# Find MIN() with a message passing parallel algorithm in a 2D-mesh of CPUs

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing, message-passing, topology, mesh-network

We have a 2D mesh CPU topology of **`p`** CPUs ( in a `squareroot(p) * squareroot(p)` 2D mesh ).

What does this mean for a parallel algorithm that tries to **find the `MIN( X )`** value in a set **`X`** of `x`-i values?

Lets assume for simplicity that at the start of the algorithm every CPU has a subset of `x`-i's.